# Save the execution progress of a jupyter cell and resume it later

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I was running a training algo inside a Jupyter Notebook. The cell was supposed to take about 20 mins to run. At about 10 mins into the execution, my power went off and I had to just shutdown my PC, and restart everything from the beginning after power came back on.   Is there a way to pause the execution, save the results/the half trained model and load it again after an hour ?